# How to determine efficiency?

Tags: c#, lambda, clr

How do I compare these two iterations to determine which is most efficient?

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    .Where(p => p.StartTime >= _createdOn)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

vs

```
foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").Where(p => p.StartTime >= _createdOn))
    proc.Kill();
```

Comment: Time it with a stopwatch from the diagnostics namespace (assuming you mean manually). You do, however, have certain tools in VS that will let you profile your code.

Comment: But beware premature optimization. Unless you are seeing significant performance problems, it's likely to be a non-issue.

Comment: [Semi-relevant blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) - perhaps not the first point, but the rest about whether it's even worth worrying about.

Comment: Very good points.  I wonder if it ever matters regarding time.  For this case (since both are quick) I'm not sure that efficiency can be measured by time.  I wonder how each compiles to CLR.

Comment: I ditto the above comments, based on assumptions I'm making on the context of your code - I'd say the difference in performance is negligible. But beware - the difference between calling `ToList` or not can *definitely* matter in certain scenarios. `ToList` will go and fetch an entire collection (from a DB, for example), whereas iterating over a well-implemented IEnumerable may `MoveNext` if and when it needs to. It's called lazy-loading, and it can matter.

Comment: @DanAndrews - quick hint, to see the result of your code (i.e. the compiled version), look into using reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Answer (score -1):

The *actual* difference can only be determined by running it both ways in exact situations and *measuring* by using `Stopwatch` or other profiling tools, however here are a few observations:

- The only real difference is the call to `ToList()` which is necessary to use `.ForEach()`.  Other than that they are equivalent.
- Since I would assume that this is not run very often (how often do you need to kill every Excel process?) the performance difference should be immaterial in this scenario.
- You may be fixing the *symptom* rather than the *problem*.  I would be curious why you have have multiple excel processes that you need to kill.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. It needs some elaboration on the 'how', i.e. the 'measuring' that you mention.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ "How do I compare these two iterations to determine which is most efficient?" --> "The actual difference can only be determined by running it both ways in exact situations and measuring,"

Comment: So your answer is to run it both ways and measure? This is a question specific to C#, it warrants a C#-based answer at the least. That's too vague.

Comment: The Excel processes are arbitrary in relationship to the question.  The question is really, 'foreach' vs 'ToList().ForEach'.  I'm not fixing a symptom, I'm just asking for efficiency.  I'm just refactoring legacy code  which spawned the question.

Comment: @JayMee Fair enough - Added a few suggestions on measurement.  That wasn't the heart of my answer, though - the fact that they're largely equivalent and that it's fixing the _symptom_ rather than the _problem_ were my main points.

Comment: @DanAndrews It may be arbitrary for the question _in general_ but it may help the OP by focusing on the _problem_ rather than the _symptom_.  A classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ It's not just [my answer](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), either.

Answer (score -1):

They are almost absolutely the same. Time consuming operations here are `Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")`, `p.StartTime` and `proc.Kill()`. You are doing the same amount of them in both cases. Everything else just takes very short time. If you want some real optimization here, you can experiment with WinAPI to do those long operations, sometimes it works faster.

EDIT:
I measured speed of these operations before, for my own project. But I didn't have exact numbers, so I rechecked again.

These are my results:

Process.GetProcessesByName():

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
}
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - start;
```

It takes **5 seconds** for every 1000 of opeartions.

p.Kill():

```
TimeSpan duratiom = TimeSpan.Zero;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    Process p = Process.Start("c:/windows/notepad");
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    p.Kill();
    duratiom += DateTime.Now - start;
}
```

It takes **300 millisecond** for every 1000 operations. Still a big number.

And StartTime, just compare numbers:

Without p.StartTime:

```
Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    ps.Where(p => true).ToList();
}
TimeSpan duratiom = DateTime.Now - start;
```

**6 milliseconds**

With p.StartTime:

```
Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    ps.Where(p => p.StartTime < DateTime.Now).ToList();
}
TimeSpan duratiom = DateTime.Now - start;
```

**408 milliseconds**

So, these numbers tell me that there is no point to optimize .Where(), ToList() or foreach. Operations with Process take dozens times more time anyway. Also, I know about profilers, and I use them to measure and optimize, but I made these examples to get the exact numbers and to show the point.

Comment: Why would there be a problem with deferred execution? (Note that `Process.GetProcessesByName` returns a `Process[]`.)

Comment: Terrible answer. `Time consuming operations here are` how do you know what is time consuming and what isn't? Read my comment above regarding `ToList`.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I edited my answer, added examples to explain my opinion better. Is it still terrible?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I guess you are rigth, I removed that part.